# How to get Split container inside the new custom tab in Existing Sales order screen

Tags: acumatica

Am trying to bring Two grids in one tab in Acumatica base sales order screen 
Like below show 
Ex:In custom PAX tab with "Passengers" grid and "Flights" grid  by using Split container

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d89mn.png)

Can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `PXSplitContainer` with the split bar set to `Vertical` orientation.

ASPX Code:

```
  <px:PXTabItem>
    <Template>
      <px:PXSplitContainer runat="server" Orientation="Vertical" SplitterPosition="640" ID="gridContainer" Height="100%" Width="100%" BorderWidth="14px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Transparent" AllowResize="True">
        <AutoSize Enabled="True" Container="Parent" />
        <Template1>
          <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="gridLeft" Height="100%" SkinID="Details" Caption="Left Grid Caption" CaptionVisible="True" Width="640px" SyncPosition="True" Style='height:100%;width:100%;'>
            <Levels>
              <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="LeftDataView">
                <Columns>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="columnX" />
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="columnY" />
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="columnZ" />
                </Columns>
              </px:PXGridLevel>
            </Levels>
          </px:PXGrid>
        </Template1>
        <Template2>
          <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="gridRight" Height="100%" SkinID="Inquire" Caption="Right Grid Caption" CaptionVisible="True" Width="100%" SyncPosition="True" Style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
            <Levels>
              <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="RightDataView">
                <Columns>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="columnX" />
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="columnY" />
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="columnZ" />
                </Columns>
              </px:PXGridLevel>
            </Levels>
          </px:PXGrid>
        </Template2>
      </px:PXSplitContainer>
    </Template>
  </px:PXTabItem>
```

It is  easier to make these kind of modifications using EDIT ASPX feature.

Additional information on adding Split Containers can be found here:
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/05/split-container-in-browser.html